# How to iterate through inputting a list of lists to a form with selenium and python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an html form where I would like to enter data for a test. The html form looks like this:

```
    <h2>Submit a new OBRF</h2>  
    <form action="scripts/submitform.php" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="branch-select">Branch:</label>
                <select name="branch" id="branch-select">
                    <option value="">--Please choose a branch--</option>
                    <option value="motown">Motown</option>
                    <option value="south">South</option>
                    <option value="west">West</option>
                    <option value="midwest">MidWest</option>
                    <option value="midatlantic">MidAtlantic</option>
                    <option value="carolinas">Carolinas</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="contract-type-select">Contract Type:</label>
                <select name="contract_type" id="contract-type-select">
                    <option value="">--Please choose a contract type--</option>
                    <option value="w2/vacation/exempt">W2 with vacation (exempt)</option>
                    <option value="w2/vacation/non-exempt">W2 with vacation (non-exempt)</option>
                    <option value="w2/no-vacation/exempt">W2 without vacation (exempt)</option>
                    <option value="w2/no-vacation/non-exempt">W2 without vacation (non-exempt)</option>
                    <option value="1099">1099</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="start-date-select">Start Date:</label>
                <input type="date" id="start-date-select" name="sdate" required>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="onboarding-type-select">Onboarding type:</label>
                <select name="onboarding_type" id="onboarding-type-select">
                    <option value="">--Please select an onboarding type--</option>
                    <option value="new-hire">New Hire</option>
                    <option value="rehire">Rehire</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="consutlant-status-select">Consultant Status:</label>
                <select name="consultant_status" id="consutlant-status-select">
                    <option value="">--Please select a consultant status--</option>
                    <option value="full-time">Full Time</option>
                    <option value="part-time">Part Time</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="reporting-type-select">Reporting Type:</label>
                <select name="reporting_type" id="reporting-type-select">
                    <option value="">--Please select a reporting type--</option>
                    <option value="cto">CTO</option>
                    <option value="fixed">Fixed Fee</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="placementid">Tracker Placement ID:</label>
                <input type="number" id="placementid" name="tracker_placement_id" required>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="pay-cycle-select">Pay Cycle:</label>
                <select name="pay_cycle" id="pay-cycle-select">
                    <option value="">--Please select a pay cycle--</option>
                    <option value="bi-monthly">Bi-Monthly</option>
                    <option value="weekly">Weekly</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="first-name">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="first-name" name="first_name">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="last-name">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="last-name" name="last_name">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="middle-name">Middle Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="middle-name" name="middle_name">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="nick-name">Nick Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="nick-name" name="nick_name">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="customer-select">Customer:</label>
                <select name="customer" id="customer-select">
                    <option value="">--Please select a customer--</option>
                    <option value="wellsfargomrs">Wells Fargo MRS</option>
                    <option value="wellsfargonon-it">Wells Fargo Non-IT</option>
                    <option value="cambia">Cambia</option>
                    <option value="chevron">Chevron</option>
                    <option value="farmers">Farmers</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="consumer-lending-select">Wells Fargo Consumer Lending Hire:</label>
                <select name="wf_consumer_lending" id="consumer-lending-select">
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="mailing-address">Mailing Address:</label>
                <input type="text" id="mailing-address" name="mailing_address">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="email-address">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email-address" name="email_address">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="cell-phone">Cell Phone:</label>
                <input type="text" id="cell-phone" name="cell_phone" title="Please provide a valid 10 digit phone number" pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" required> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="ssn-input">SSN:</label>
                <input type="text" id="ssn-input" name="ssn" title="Please provide a valid 9 digit ssn" pattern="[0-9]{9}" required> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="dob-select">DOB:</label>
                <input type="date" id="dob-select" name="dob" required>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="military-veteran">Military Veteran Status:</label>
                <select name="militray_veteran" id="military-veteran">
                    <option value="no">No</option>
                    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="unknown">Unknown</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="military-spouse">Military Spouse Status:</label>
                <select name="militray_spouse" id="military-spouse">
                    <option value="no">No</option>
                    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="unknown">Unknown</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="candidate-source-select">Candidate Source:</label>
                <select name="candidate_source" id="candidate-source-select">
                    <option value="">--Please select a candidate source--</option>
                    <option value="dice">Dice</option>
                    <option value="careerbuilder">Career Builder</option>
                    <option value="linkedin">LinkedIn</option>
                    <option value="indeed">InDeed</option>
                    <option value="referral">Referral</option>
                    <option value="networkpartner">Network Partner</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="candidateid">Tracker Candidate ID:</label>
                <input type="number" id="candidateid" name="tracker_candidate_id">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="work-auth-select">Visa or Work Authorization:</label>
                <select name="visa" id="work-auth-select">
                    <option value="">--Please select candidate work authorization or visa type--</option>
                    <option value="usc">US Citizen</option>
                    <option value="greencard">Green Card/Perm Resident</option>
                    <option value="h4">H4 EAD</option>
                    <option value="h1b">H1b Visa</option>
                    <option value="l2">L2 EAD</option>
                    <option value="asylum">Asylum EAD</option>
                    <option value="opt/cpt">OPT or CPT EAD</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="visa-exp-select">Visa Expiration:</label>
                <input type="date" id="visa-exp-select" name="visa_expiration_date" required>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="end-date-select">End Date:</label>
                <input type="date" id="end-date-select" name="end_date" required>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="job-title">Job Title:</label>
                <input type="text" id="job-title" name="candidate_job_title">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="hiring-manager">Site Supervisor (Hiring Manager):</label>
                <input type="text" id="hiring-manager" name="hiring_manager_name">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="work-location">Work Location (or Remote):</label>
                <input type="text" id="work-location" name="candidate_work_location">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="recruiter">Recrutier:</label>
                <input type="text" id="recruiter" name="placement_recruiter">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="sourcer">Sourcer:</label>
                <input type="text" id="sourcer" name="placement_sourcer">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="am">Account Manager:</label>
                <input type="text" id="am" name="placement_am">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="hourly-pay-rate">Hourly Wage:</label>
                <input type="number" id="hourly-pay-rate" name="hourly_wage" step="0.01" required>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="health">Health Benefits</label>
                <select name="health_benefits" id="health">
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="misc-exp-type">Misc Expense Type:</label>
                <select name="misc_exp_type" id="misc-exp-type">
                    <option value="">N/A</option>
                    <option value="npa">NPA Fee</option>
                    <option value="immigration">Immigration Expense</option>
                    <option value="referral">Referral</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="misc-exp-amount">Misc Expense Amount:</label>
                <input type="number" id="misc-exp-amount" name="misc_exp_amount" step="0.01" placeholder="Enter 0 if there is none" required>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="np-name">Network Partner:</label>
                <input type="text" id="np-name" name="network_partner_name" placehodler="Please enter N/A if no NP">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="billing">Bill Rate:</label>
                <input type="number" id="billing" name="bill_rate" step="0.01" required>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="cto">CTO:</label>
                <input type="number" id="cto" name="placement_cto" step="0.01" required>
            </li>
            
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
            
        </ul>
    </form>
```

I created this script to input data via python/selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/davidsafran/chromedriver/chromedriver')

driver.get('http://192.168.1.97/OBA/loginsys/login.php')

user_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/form/div[1]/input')
user_input.send_keys('testuser')

password_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/form/div[2]/input')
password_input.send_keys('password')

login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/form/div[3]/input')
login_button.click()

driver.get('http://192.168.1.97/OBA/form.php')

branch_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="branch-select"]'))
branch_select.select_by_visible_text('West')

contract_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contract-type-select"]'))
contract_select.select_by_visible_text('1099')

startdate_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="start-date-select"]')
startdate_input.send_keys('12/01/2021')

onboarding_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="onboarding-type-select"]'))
onboarding_select.select_by_visible_text('New Hire')

consultantstatus_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="consutlant-status-select"]'))
consultantstatus_select.select_by_visible_text('Full Time')

reportingtype_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="reporting-type-select"]'))
reportingtype_select.select_by_visible_text('CTO')

trackerid_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="placementid"]')
trackerid_input.send_keys('123456')

paycycle_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pay-cycle-select"]'))
paycycle_select.select_by_visible_text('Bi-Monthly')

firstname_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="first-name"]')
firstname_input.send_keys('Donald')

lastname_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="last-name"]')
lastname_input.send_keys('Draper')

middlename_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="middle-name"]')
middlename_input.send_keys('Dick')

nickname_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nick-name"]')
nickname_input.send_keys('Don')

customer_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="customer-select"]'))
customer_select.select_by_visible_text('Chevron')

consumerlending_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="consumer-lending-select"]'))
consumerlending_select.select_by_visible_text('No')

address_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mailing-address"]')
address_input.send_keys('1234 Test Lane')

email_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email-address"]')
email_input.send_keys('test@email.com')

phone_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cell-phone"]')
phone_input.send_keys('1234567890')

ssn_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ssn-input"]')
ssn_input.send_keys('123456789')

dob_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dob-select"]')
dob_input.send_keys('05-15-1925')

milvetstatus_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="military-veteran"]'))
milvetstatus_select.select_by_visible_text('No')

milspousestatus_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="military-spouse"]'))
milspousestatus_select.select_by_visible_text('No')

candidatesource_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="candidate-source-select"]'))
candidatesource_select.select_by_visible_text('Dice')

candidateid_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="candidateid"]')
candidateid_input.send_keys('12345')

visa_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="work-auth-select"]'))
visa_select.select_by_visible_text('US Citizen')

visaexpiration_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="visa-exp-select"]')
visaexpiration_input.send_keys('11-20-2021')

contractenddate_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="end-date-select"]')
contractenddate_input.send_keys('12-01-2022')

jobttile_inout = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="job-title"]')
jobttile_inout.send_keys('Creative Director')

hiringmanager_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="hiring-manager"]')
hiringmanager_input.send_keys('Roger Stirling')

worklocation_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="work-location"]')
worklocation_input.send_keys('5000 Madison Ave.')

recruiter_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="recruiter"]')
recruiter_input.send_keys('Jim')

sourcer_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sourcer"]')
sourcer_input.send_keys('James')

am_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="am"]')
am_input.send_keys('John')

hourlypay_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="hourly-pay-rate"]')
hourlypay_input.send_keys('150.00')

healthbenefits_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="health"]'))
healthbenefits_select.select_by_visible_text('Yes')

miscexptype_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="misc-exp-type"]'))
miscexptype_select.select_by_visible_text('N/A')

misexpamount_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="misc-exp-amount"]')
misexpamount_input.send_keys('0')

npa_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="np-name"]')
npa_input.send_keys('0')

billrate_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="billing"]')
billrate_input.send_keys('200.00')

cto_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cto"]')
cto_input.send_keys('20.00')

submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/form/ul/input')
submit_button.click()
```

And this script to pull test data from a Google Sheet in a list of list format where each list is a row of data for a single form submission:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'keys.json'

creds = None
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = '1f87n2YD_OD1QYpAfuHwONj6BbyNEMl_FT2ubxTF1CQ4'


service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

# Call the Sheets API
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                            range="data!A2:AM11").execute()

values = result.get('values', [])
```

So far I have tried a few combinations of for and while loops but nothing seems to work and I have only gotten the code to iterate through the first list. Any suggestions on how to approach or solve this?

Comment: Can you clarify by iterating through list of lists?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Let me try to clarify. I have test data in an Google Sheet that I would like to run through my form using Python/Selenium. Each row represents a different form submission that I would like to submit as a test. I am pulling the data from Google Sheet via API and arranging in a list of lists where each submission is a list and all submissions are contained in a master list like such: [[Submission 1][Submission 2] [Submission 3] etc...].